# Why doesn't this JSON load in python?

Tags: python, json

For a couple of days i've been trying to learn how to use JSON in python, but even if i copy everything from tutorials it still won't load.

```
    import json

data = '''
{
    "people":[
    {
    "name": "veljko",
    "age":"20",
    "email": veljkov02@gail.com,
    "educated": "true"
    } ,
    {
    "name":"aleksandar",
    "age":"24",
    "email":"marko99@gmail.com",
    "educated":"false"
    }
    ]
}
'''
men = json.loads(data)
print(men)
```

(Ignore the random words used in code, it's just how i learn)
It just keeps giving the same error messages, i've tried with the most simple JSON but it's still the same.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*********\Desktop\code3\json.py", line 21, in <module>
    men = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Users\************\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\*************\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode.
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\************\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 14 (char 75)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help, i'm a begginer and am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: You need double quotes around the email address: `"email": "veljkov02@gail.com",`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quotes around `veljkov02@gail.com`. You need to change it to `"veljkov02@gail.com"`, so that it is interpreted as a string. The exception tells you which line and character the error is at, so double check that line when you get errors like these.